# Finding the image of a parameterised surface $S$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $\vec{X}=\langle s^2\cos(t),s^2\sin(t),s\rangle$
>   with $s\in [-3,3]$ and $t\in [0,2\pi]$
>
> Find an equation for the image of $\vec{X}$ in the form $F(x,y,z)=0$

Finding myself lost here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $ x^2 + y^2 - z^4 = 0 $. $ x, y \in [-9, 9] $, $ z \in [-3, 3] $.

$ \sin^2 t + \cos^2 t = 1 $ is just a very commonly used trick.